# No property found

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Im getting an exception.  Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property start found for type.. I dont know whats wrong about this code but i almost did everything in my backend side using all of this principles, seems that something is missing..

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pages/{pageNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getStories(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, Model model) {

    Page<Article> page = frontService.getStories(pageNumber);

        int current = page.getNumber() + 1;
        int begin = Math.max(1, current - 5);
        int end = Math.min(begin + 10, page.getTotalPages());

        model.addAttribute("deploymentLog", page);
        model.addAttribute("beginIndex", begin);
        model.addAttribute("endIndex", end);
        model.addAttribute("currentIndex", current);

    return "NewFile";
}
```

Service

```
public interface FrontStoryService {
     public Page<Article> getStories(Integer pageNumber);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FrontStoryServiceImpl implements FrontStoryService {
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 50;

    @Inject private FrontEndStoriesRepository storiesRepo;
    public Page<Article> getStories(Integer pageNumber) {
        PageRequest request =
                new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1, PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.DESC, "startTime");
        System.out.println(request);
            return storiesRepo.findAll(request);

    }

}
```

repo

```
@Repository("frontService")
public interface FrontEndStoriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> { }
```

error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property start found for type com.jwlayug.atriev.model.Article
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:271)
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:401)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:365)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:449)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:430)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:312)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:282)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.findAll(Unknown Source)
com.jwlayug.atriev.service.FrontStoryServiceImpl.getStories(FrontStoryServiceImpl.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getStories(Unknown Source)
com.jwlayug.atriev.controller.FrontController.getStories(FrontController.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

model

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
@Entity
@Table(name="tblArticle")
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long articleID; 
    private String title;
    private String author;
    @Type(type="text")
    private String content;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date dateCreated;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date dateUpdated;
    private boolean publish;
    private boolean send;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=UserSession.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserSession userSession;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mail", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Recipient> sendEmail = new ArrayList<Recipient>();
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Media.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Media media;
    public Article(){}


    public Article(String title, String author,
            String content,UserSession userSession) {
        super();


        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.content = content;
        this.dateCreated = new Date();
        this.dateUpdated = new Date();
        this.send = false;
        this.publish = false;
        this.userSession = userSession;

    }


    public Long getArticleID() {
        return articleID;
    }


    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }


    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getDateUpdated() {
        return dateUpdated;
    }
    public Media getMedia() {
        return media;
    }
    public List<Recipient> getSendEmail() {
        return sendEmail;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public UserSession getUserSession() {
        return userSession;
    }
    public boolean isPublish() {
        return publish;
    }
    public boolean isSend() {
        return send;
    }
    public void setArticleID(Long articleID) {
        this.articleID = articleID;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
        this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
    }
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        dateUpdated = dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate() {
        dateUpdated = new Date();
    }
    public void setMedia(Media media) {
        this.media = media;
    }


    public void setPublish(boolean publish) {
        this.publish = publish;
    }




    public void setSend(boolean send) {
        this.send = send;
    }


    public void setSendEmail(List<Recipient> sendEmail) {
        this.sendEmail = sendEmail;
    }


    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public void setUserSession(UserSession userSession) {
        this.userSession = userSession;
    }


}
```

Comment: add your hbm and model class to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says that you want to order articles by `startTime`.

The exception tells otherwise. It shows that it actually wants to sort articles by `start`.

And both won't work anyway since, as the exception says, there is no property `start` or `startTime` in Article. So you can't sort articles by `start` or `startTime` since thay don't have one.